# ngOnInit called in the middle of component lifetime

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I having some issues with `text.component` (selector `app-text`) initialising in the middle of the app life time (not just when I create it).

This is app.component.html:

```
  <div class="container-fluid" *ngFor="let text of texts;let i=index">
    <app-text (textInfoEmitter)="dataFromChild($event)" [elementId]=i  [ngStyle]="{'transform': getRotation(i), 'font-size.px':getFontSize(i)}" ></app-text>
  </div>
```

I am emitting the data from `app-text` with `textInfoEmitter` function and updating the model in `app.component.ts` with `dataFromChild(e)`.

I noticed that everytime `textInfoEmitter` emits, `app-text` gets reinitialised. I can confirm that because, `ngOnInit` and `constructor` functions get called.

This is app.component.ts file:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  texts: [TextModel];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.texts = [
      {
        rotation: 30,
        fontSize: 16,
        offset: { left: 120, top: 200 },
        scale: 1.4
      }
    ]
  }

  dataFromChild(e) {
    this.texts[e.elementID] = {
      rotation: e.rotation,
      fontSize: e.fontSize,
      offset:e.offset,
      scale: 1
    }

  }
  getRotation(i: number) {
    return "rotate(" + this.texts[i].rotation + "deg)";
  }
  getFontSize(i: number) {
    return this.texts[i].fontSize;
  }
}
```

The `text.component.ts` is convoluted and I haven't found a way to replicate a complex Angular project online. This is the emit helper function I call:

```
  emitData(e){
    if ($(e).hasClass("h")){
      this.parentId = $(e).attr("id");
    }else{
      this.parentId = $(e).parent().attr("id");
    }

    this.textInfoEmitter.emit(
      {
        elementID: this.parentId,
        rotation: this.delta.circleX,
        fontSize: this.delta.fontSize,
        offset: {
          left: this.drag.x,
          top: this.drag.y
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

`delta` and `drag` are models in `text.component.ts`.

My question is, in what situations does a component get reinitialised during lifetime? How can this be prevented?

**Replica of a problem.** I am essentialy doing the same, using ngFor directive and updating the model with EventEmitter. This time, ngOnInit does not get fired when the model updates.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var $;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div class="container-fluid" *ngFor="let text of texts; let i = index">
<app-text id="i" (dataEmitter)="setData($event)" [ngStyle]="{'transform': getRotation()}"></app-text>
</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  texts = [
    {rotate:10}
  ];

  ngOnInit(){
  }
  getRotation(){
    return "rotate("+this.texts[0].rotate+"deg)";
  }
  setData(e){
      this.texts[0].rotate = e;
  } 
}
```

text.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
declare var $;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-text',
  template:`<div tabindex="-1" (mousedown)="mousedown($event)" (focusout)="focusout($event)">Text</div>` ,
  styleUrls: ['./text.component.css']
})
export class TextComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() dataEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ng on Init");
  }
  mousedown(e){
    $(e.target).focus();
    $(e.target).addClass("selected");
    this.dataEmitter.emit(50);
  }
  focusout(e){
    console.log("f out");
    $(e.target).removeClass("selected");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are changing your `this.texts` property which is that `*ngFor` binds to which is, in turn, a parent of your `app-text` component.

what that means is:

1. you change `this.texts`
2. your DOM elements created by `*ngFor` for previous value of `this.texts` gets removed (together with all `app-text` components which are children)
3. new iteration through `this.texts` happens with new instances of `app-text` for each

Comment: I've added another code, which is a replica of a problem. I am using ngFor and emitting data, just a s before. But in this case, ngOnInit does not get fired when the model updates.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dee zg the problem was solved.

When model changes, Angular does indeed reinitialise the whole contents of *ngFor directive. Under the hood, it tries to determine if it needs to destroy and create dom elements.

If you modify the whole model object, angular will create fresh dom elements, but if you modify just properties of the model object, it will not.

For example:

`this.texts[0] = {rotation:0, fontSize:23}` will cause the contents of ngFor to be destroyed and recreated.

But if you use this:

```
this.texts[0].rotation = 0;
this.texts[0].fontSize = 23;
```

it will not.

Comment: of course because that doesnt change the reference to the object.